# Why I can't install ffmpeg on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, yum, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg to my CentOS 7 server but I can't, it say we missing some libs that I can't find where and how to install them.

This is command i used and the error occured:

```
[root@www13 ~]# yum install ffmpeg -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: www.ftp.ne.jp
* extras: www.ftp.ne.jp
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: www.ftp.ne.jp
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ffmpeg.x86_64 0:2.6.8-3.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ffmpeg-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.8-3.el7.nux for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libswscale.so.3(LIBSWSCALE_3)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libswresample.so.1(LIBSWRESAMPLE_1)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpostproc.so.53(LIBPOSTPROC_53)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.54(LIBAVUTIL_54)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavresample.so.2(LIBAVRESAMPLE_2)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.56(LIBAVFORMAT_56)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavfilter.so.5(LIBAVFILTER_5)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavdevice.so.56(LIBAVDEVICE_56)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.56(LIBAVCODEC_56)(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libvdpau.so.1()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libswscale.so.3()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libswresample.so.1()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpostproc.so.53()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.54()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavresample.so.2()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.56()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavfilter.so.5()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavdevice.so.56()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.56()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package SDL.x86_64 0:1.2.15-14.el7 will be installed
---> Package ffmpeg-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.8-3.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxvidcore.so.4()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libx265.so.79()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.142()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libva.so.1()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsoxr.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmp3lame.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfdk-aac.so.1()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfaac.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libass.so.5()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
---> Package libavdevice.x86_64 0:2.6.8-3.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1()(64bit) for package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdc1394.so.22()(64bit) for package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
---> Package libvdpau.x86_64 0:1.1-2.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package faac.x86_64 0:1.28-6.0.el7.nux will be installed
---> Package fdk-aac.x86_64 0:0.1.4-1 will be installed
---> Package ffmpeg-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.8-3.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libass.so.5()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
---> Package lame-libs.x86_64 0:3.99.5-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libavdevice.x86_64 0:2.6.8-3.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1()(64bit) for package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64
---> Package libdc1394.x86_64 0:2.2.0-4.el7.nux will be installed
---> Package libva.x86_64 0:1.0.16-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0()(64bit) for package: libva-1.0.16-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package soxr.x86_64 0:0.1.1-2.el7.nux will be installed
---> Package x264-libs.x86_64 0:0.142-11.20141221git6a301b6.el7.nux will be installed
---> Package x265-libs.x86_64 0:1.9-1.el7.nux will be installed
---> Package xvidcore.x86_64 0:1.3.2-5.el7.nux will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libva-1.0.16-3.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech)
       Requires: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (forensics)
       Requires: libopenal.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (forensics)
       Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
```

Where and how I can install libudev, libopenal, libass for my server?

Edit:
just run command @Alexander T said:

```
[root@www13 ~]# yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
PLESK_17_5_3-extras             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
PLESK_17_NGINX                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
PLESK_17_PHP56                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
PLESK_17_PHP70                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
base                            | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
extras                          | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
forensics                       | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
forensics-splunk                | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
linuxtech                       | 2.6 kB  00:00:00     
nux-dextop                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
plesk-migrator                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
plesk-migrator-tp               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
updates                         | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: www.ftp.ne.jp
 * extras: www.ftp.ne.jp
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: www.ftp.ne.jp
Package epel-release-7-9.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

then reinstall ffmpeg but still error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do all right, as @Bert said, but this libraries should be installed from EPEL repository. You could install it by command `yum install epel-release` and after this dependency errors will gone away.

Here list of packets that installs from EPEL(filtered `yum` output):

```
 lame-libs                                                        x86_64                                                 3.99.5-8.el7                                                                        epel                                                       343 k
 libass                                                           x86_64                                                 0.13.4-1.el7                                                                        epel                                                        92 k
 libdc1394                                                        x86_64                                                 2.2.2-3.el7                                                                         epel                                                       121 k
 libva                                                            x86_64                                                 1.2.1-3.el7                                                                         epel                                                        68 k
 openal-soft                                                      x86_64                                                 1.16.0-3.el7                                                                        epel                                                       282 k
 schroedinger                                                     x86_64                                                 1.0.11-4.el7                                                                        epel                                                       291 k
 soxr                                                             x86_64                                                 0.1.2-1.el7                                                                         epel                                                        77 k
```

Comment: True, I did not think of EPEL not being installed at all. This step is nearly basic for me at server install. :)

Comment: @Bert it seen in beginning of `yum` output.

Comment: I just run it, then reinstall ffmpeg but still error

Comment: Same error? So what CentOS did you install? What ISO did you download?

Comment: @ThinhPhan please provide output with new error.

Comment: @ThinhPhan looks like you have disabled `epel` or it's removed try to run `yum install ffmpeg -y --enablerepo=epel`. If this not help, try to reinstall epel `yum remove epel-release -y && yum install epel-release -y` and try to install `ffmpeg` again.

Comment: @AlexanderT, you are right, my epel is disable, just run your command and it's success install now. Thanks you very much!!!

So how can I vote your reply is right answer? Or I just vote your comment?

Comment: @ThinhPhan vote my answer.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

Install the EPEL release repo

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

Import the GPG key for the Nux repo

```
rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
```

Install the NUX desktop release repo

```
rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

Run yum, enabling the EPEL and Nux desktop repo, and install ffmpeg

```
yum -y --enablerepo=epel,nux-dextop install ffmpeg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You saved me. People like you are the real PROs, I have really surfed more than 100 pages searching for this. Everything was same, just passing `--enablerepo=epel,nux-dextop` really made it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Install the nux-dextop repository then run yum install ffmpeg

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=48930

Comment: as you can see, `nux-desktop` already installed.

Comment: Strange, for me it works like a charm after adding only the nux-desktop repository. Which CentOS 7 did you install? Minimal or Desktop?

Comment: @Bert how do I know it's Mininal or Desktop? I'm newbie and I'm install it by command from remote server